# Hex values are being written in the wrong order

Tags: c, hex

Using the following code to write to a file

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    uint32_t pattern1, pattern2;
    int i, times;
    sscanf("ae75db0f", "%x", &pattern1); 
    sscanf("518a24f0", "%x", &pattern2);
    FILE * outFile = fopen(argv[1],"wb");
    printf ("Pattern 1: %0x \nPattern 2: %0x \n", pattern1, pattern2);

    times = 524288; // Write out 4 mB of data

    for (i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        fwrite(&pattern1, 4, 1, outFile);
        fwrite(&pattern2, 4, 1, outFile);
    }
    fclose (outFile);
}
```

On the command line I do xxd file | less

```
00018c0: f024 8a51 0fdb 75ae f024 8a51 0fdb 75ae  .$.Q..u..$.Q..u.
00018d0: f024 8a51 0fdb 75ae f024 8a51 0fdb 75ae  .$.Q..u..$.Q..u.
00018e0: f024 8a51 0fdb 75ae f024 8a51 0fdb 75ae  .$.Q..u..$.Q..u.
00018f0: f024 8a51 0fdb 75ae f024 8a51 0fdb 75ae  .$.Q..u..$.Q..u.
```

It's not showing the "correct" values that were supposed to be written to the file itself.

Comment: Looks like an endian-ness issue.

Comment: As an exercise you can look at the difference between `od -t x2 file` and `od -t x4 file`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the world of the endianness:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

x86/x64 architectures (like most architectures nowadays) are little endian: it means multi-bytes values are stored in memory with the Least Significant Bytes first (low memory address).

Comment: Clearly Falcata is using faulty hardware.  On my system, I get this: `0000000: ae75 db0f 518a 24f0 ae75 db0f 518a 24f0  .u..Q.$..u..Q.$.`

Comment: I did not know about endianess, little did I know that I was using arm little endian, hence the reverse order. You learn something new everyday!

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on @ouah's answer, you must determine the endian-ness of your system.

In this example, you must reverse the byte order in your example, like this:

```
pattern1 = (pattern1 >> 16) | (pattern1 << 16);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have discovered [Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).  If you want to change the order to the other way around, look at functions like `htonl`.

Answer (score 1):

It might be showing the correct order, the truth is that you cannot make such an assertion without knowledge of your platform's [Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

This is an excellent example why one should take great care when reading in non-bytes and writing out bytes.

Answer (score 1):

If you read them back as `uint32_t`s on the same machine they would come back as the same values.

What you see on disk is the same as what you would see in memory if you looked at the underlying `char`s.